# Please explain me this recursion function

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

So we have this piece of code, that generates array using recursion function and then another recursion function that multiplies all numbers in the array, like factorial. What I don't understand is this part `stack[x - 1] = int * stack[x - 1];` what exactly `stack[x - 1]` does in this case? If everytime the function calls itself, it .pop() the last element in array, that means everytime the length of array gets shorter until we hit base case `x === 0`, then why we have to substract -1 from its length manually anyway? Thanks.

```
var stack = [];

function countDown(int) {
  stack.push(int);
  if (int === 1) {  
    return 1;
  }
    return countDown(int - 1);
}

function multiplyEach() {
  // Remove the last value of the stack 
  // and assign it to the variable int
  int = stack.pop();
  x = stack.length;
  // Base case
  if (x === 0) {
    return int;
  }
  // Recursive case
  else {
    stack[x - 1] = int * stack[x - 1];
    return multiplyEach();
  }
}

// Call the function countDown(7)
countDown(7);
// And then print out the value returned by multiplyEach()
console.log(multiplyEach());
```

Comment: "then why we have to substract -1 from its length manually anyway? " if you don't subtract 1 then you'll never get to the base case.

Comment: Isn't it self explanatory?

Comment: @AnuragAwasthi No

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because we're talking about the index not the length, and the index is 0-based.

Say we have the following array:

```
var a = [333, 555];
```

it's length is 2. But's it's items are 0 and 1. So if you make a look based on it's length, you have 2 options: a var that starts with -1 length or use -1 index at each element.

Hope I clarified.

Comment: Oh, so in my example there is 7 items in my array, but since arrays are 0-based we have only 6, starting counting from 0, so we have to substract -1 to represent 0-ish item or the first element, otherwise we never reach base case which is x===0, right?